# How to tell if the difference between two SD's is significant?

Tags: distributions

I want to tell something about predictability of health improvement results after a specific surgical procedure. I asume that the smaller the SD around the mean, the more predictable the results are.
If I want to compare two subgroups, for example males and females, I find two different means and also two different standard deviations, but the means seem to be less different than the SD's. Does this mean that there is a difference in distribution (bell curve) and how to tell if this difference is significant? In other words, I am not so much interested in the difference between the two means.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances (the SD is the square root of the variance)

Comment: Please note that in the article referenced by @tristan (+1) it says "This F-test is known to be extremely sensitive to non-normality, so Levene's test, Bartlett's test, or the Brown–Forsythe test are better tests."

Answer (score 2):

If the data are normally distributed, the F test for equality of variance can be used.  Testing a null hypothesis of equal variance against the alternative that they are different is equivalent to testing equality of standard deviation against the alternative that they are different.

Comment: Because the F test is notoriously sensitive to the normality assumption, it seems that with modern computing power nobody should be using it for comparing variances. Why not recommend a permutation test?

Comment: @whuber Or maybe a bootstrap test?  I think another point to make about the F test is that it often requires large differences for the difference to be detected (for commonly used sample sizes).

Comment: F-test, bootstrap, permutation, Levene's, Bartlett's test, or the Brown–Forsythe test? In my example, the whole group is about 8000 patients, the samples are about 2000 to 6000 patients. Which test would you than recomment?

Comment: The important thing is to avoid the F test if the data are not normal.  The other tests are all reasonable.